# Confirm/redirect functionality not working - javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here I used JavaScript to Delete an employee...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delet(emp)
{
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');
    if(answer)
    {
        window.location='delete.php?emp='+emp;
    }
}
</script>
```

By using anchor tag am calling the function of javascript ....

```
<a onclick="javascript:delet('<? echo $_GET['emp']; ?>')">
<input type="button" name="delete" id="delete" style="background: url('images/del1.jpg')no-repeat;width:50px;height:50px" value=""/></a>
```

But my problem is it is working upto showing the alert msg but after answering the alert msg it is not redirecting to the page given by me that is "delete.php?emp=+emp"

Comment: ya but it is not working...

Comment: What else does it do, just nothing? Why do you have a submit button inside of that link?

Comment: now i edited it but it is not working...@Bergi

Comment: @What's not working now? [This setup](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Bvw/4/) looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're submitting some form by clicking on that button. That submit process will overrule the `window.location` navigation request. A quick workaround would be to prevent that:

```
<a onclick="event.preventDefault(); delet('<? echo $_GET['emp']; ?>');">
// cross-browser-safe:
<a onclick="delet('<? echo $_GET['emp']; ?>'); return false">
```

but actually your markup with the nested button is quite odd. You don't need that link at all, just use

```
<form action="delete.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure');">
    <input type="hidden" name="emp" value="<? echo $_GET['emp']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" style="background: url('images/del1.jpg')no-repeat;width:50px;height:50px" value="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

Because you're nesting an `<input type="Submit"/>` inside an `<a>`, clicking the button is not the same as clicking the `<a>`, rather it "Submits" nowhere (read to the page you're already on, refreshing the page) before the `<a>` can do it's job.

[**Simple demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Bvw/) where you **don't** go to google.

```
<a href="http://google.com/"><input type="Submit"/></a>
```

---

[Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488797/#comment25418670_17488850) that the behaviour I described is **not universal** *(hello Opera, IE)* **unless a `<form>` element is present**, so [**for example**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Bvw/3/) the following

```
<form action="jail.php">
    <a href="go.php" onclick="window.location='?collect=£200';">
        <input type="submit"/>
    </a>
</form>
```

will send you directly to *jail* without passing *go* or *collecting £200* across all browsers.

Further, this only really applies to page redirection; other pieces of script may well fire before the page changes, the easiest to observe being `console.log`, `alert`, etc.

Comment: good illustration of the problem he is having, rather than direct answer. +1

Comment: At least Opera *does* go to Google. It needs a `<form>`, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Bvw/1/) will lead to Wikipedia.

Comment: @Bergi I tested in _Chrome_ and _FireFox_ and like to pretend _IE_ is a bad dream, then you tell me _Opera_ is sometimes closer to it than the other two? A nightmare! Anyway, answer updated.

Comment: @Paul Yes, Opera does emulate some strange bugs (features) of IE to be compatible to older websites. It follows the standard though, and when you put inputs into forms (where they belong to make a valid page) then it works just like Chrome of FF.